# saving the items displayed in listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am showing list of all the applications installed on the phone with the help of the packagemanager in the listview and there is a checkbox along with every application name shown in the list. I want to save the name of the applications against who the user has selected the textbox. The saved items will be used to generate a list of favorite apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can Save it in the your database while the user presses on the check box and delete if it is already present in your database if the user unchecks it.You can use listener and put your code of saving inside your listener.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a listener to your checkboxes => [OnCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html)

You will then be notified each time the state of the checkbox change, if the checkbox is checked, you can add the element to a list, if it is unchecked, you can remove the element from your list.

This requires you to have your own adapter thought.

Good luck and have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You need to make custom listview with checkboxes : here is one **[example](http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/listview-with-checkboxes-without-listactivity.php)** for you.

You will need to have one Button below/above the Listview clicking on what you can take all the items and store it into your database : a complete **[Articale](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)** for that.

Now you can fetch the data from database anytime to show those favourite apps.